# Problem with hyperlink

Tags: hyperref

By compiling the following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{longfbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={theorem}{theorems}]{theo}[2][]{%
breakable,enhanced,colback=blue!5!white,
colframe=blue!75!black,
colbacktitle=cyan!50!green,
coltitle=blue!25!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,colback=cyan!50!red!25!white},title=Theorem~\thetcbcounter~#2,label=#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[mytheo]{(My Theorem)}
\lipsum
\end{theo}

Here is my \Cref{mytheo}.

\end{document}
```

the red link of "Theorem 0.1" in page 2 of the pdf file leads to the top of this page and not to the initial box theorem in page 1. Why?

The problem is: I need to compile the file as dvi->ps->pdf...

Comment: If I typeset with `pdflatex` (`dvips` option needs to be removed from `hyperref`), clicking the link takes me precisely to the top of the theorem in Evince PDF viewer.

Comment: The problem is: I need to compile the file as dvi->ps->pdf...
How I can solve this? C.W.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion.

You can try to label that particular place with \label{Theo} for example and put \phantomsection alongside with the label. Afterwards use \ref{Theo} to reference the theorem and see if it links directly to the box as required.